# Store os.system( 'curl -u "username:password" "https://<url>") in a python variable to stream data in another framework?

Tags: python, curl, os.system

I do a lookup on internet using CURL. I automated this using a python script to take an IP as an argument and further run CURL using that.

I tried the following:

```
maxm = os.system('curl -u  "Username : Password " %s' %url)
```

But still the output gets displayed on terminal and not as value for variable `maxm`.

I even tried `subprocess.Popen`. But that dint work though.

Seeking help to resolve this.

Regards
Richa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `subprocess.PIPE`, but the easiest way is to use [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)

```
import subprocess

maxm = subprocess.check_output('curl -u  "Username : Password " %s' % url)
```

Comment: @RichaSingh I'm glad it helps. Would you consider accept my answer :)